# Error in installing mongodb plugin in logstash

Tags: mongodb, logstash

I am using logstash 7.15.2. I need to connect mongodb in logstash so i am trying to install logstash-input-sqlite and logstash-input-mongodb. I have successfully installed logstash-input-sqlite. Facing error in mongodb plugin.

Error:

```
>logstash-plugin install logstash-input-mongodb
Using JAVA_HOME defined java: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191
WARNING, using JAVA_HOME while Logstash distribution comes with a bundled JDK
Validating logstash-input-mongodb
Resolving mixin dependencies
Installing logstash-input-mongodb
Plugin version conflict, aborting
ERROR: Installation Aborted, message: Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "jdbc-sqlite3":
  In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
    jdbc-sqlite3 (= 3.28.0)

  In Gemfile:
    logstash-input-mongodb was resolved to 0.4.1, which depends on
      jdbc-sqlite3 (= 3.8.10.1)

    logstash-input-sqlite was resolved to 3.0.4, which depends on
      jdbc-sqlite3

Running `bundle update` will rebuild your snapshot from scratch, using only
the gems in your Gemfile, which may resolve the conflict.

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "logstash":
  In Gemfile:
    logstash-input-mongodb was resolved to 0.1.1, which depends on
      logstash (< 2.0.0, >= 1.4.0)

Could not find gem 'logstash (< 2.0.0, >= 1.4.0)', which is required by gem 'logstash-input-mongodb', in rubygems repository https://rubygems.org/ or installed locally.

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "logstash-input-mongodb":
  In Gemfile:
    logstash-input-mongodb
```

Comment: This plugin is a third party plugin that is [not maintained](https://github.com/phutchins/logstash-input-mongodb/issues/101) anymore, it is probably not compatible with later versions of logstash.

Comment: So any other way to config mongo db collection in logstash input plugin.

Comment: No idea, I do not use mongodb, but the above link have some suggestions that may help.